# JavaScript event handler in progressbar prototype comes up with undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, nan

I am currently building a JavaScript object that creates a progress bar and allows the progress bar value to be incremented using click listeners on certain elements.
I am having a problem whereby when I click on a button that should increment the current value, it says the value is NaN when I alert this value to the window and I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
//Progress Bar
var ProgressBar = function(element, startVal, endVal, step, addLefts, addRights) {
    this.element = element;
    this.endVal = endVal;
    this.currentVal = startVal;
    this.step = step;
    this.addLefts = addLefts;
    this.addRights = addRights;
    var self = this;    
}

ProgressBar.prototype.initializeProgressBar = function() {
    jQuery(this.element).progressbar({
        value : this.currentVal
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < this.addLefts.length; i++) {
        this.addLefts[i].addEventListener("click", this.removeAmount, false);
    }   
    for(var i = 0; i < this.addRights.length; i++) {
        this.addRights[i].addEventListener("click", this.addAmount, false);
    }   
}

ProgressBar.prototype.addAmount = function() {  
    this.currentVal += this.step;       
    alert(this.currentVal);
}

ProgressBar.prototype.removeAmount = function() {
    this.currentVal -= this.step;
    alert(this.currentVal);
}
```

And the code to create an instance of the object

```
var addLefts = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-left");
var addRights = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-right");
var progressBar = new ProgressBar("#progress-bar", 0, jQuery(".signup-part").length, 1, addLefts, addRights);
progressBar.initializeProgressBar();
```

Why is 'this.currentVal' property returning NaN from within the `addAmount` and `removeAmount` functions?

Comment: that means either of `this.currentVal += this.step` or `this.currentVal -= this.step` is causing the issue.. check the value and type of `this.currentVal` and `this.step`prior to the operation

Comment: you will be losing your "this".  put a console.log(this); at the beginning of the function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add `this.addAmount` or `this.removeAmount` as the event handler, it will be called in the context of the element, not the`ProgressBar` instance.

To work around this, you can use `bind()` to force it to be called in the correct context.

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.addLefts.length; i++) {
    this.addLefts[i].addEventListener("click", this.removeAmount.bind(this), false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to bind your this to your function...

```
this.addRights[i].addEventListener("click", this.addAmount.bind(this), false);
```

if you use something like underscore you can do something a bit more tricky,  have a single :-

```
ProgressBar.prototype.change = function(sign) {
    this.currentVal += (this.step * sign);
}
```

and then :-

```
this.addLefts[i].addEventListener("click",  _.partial(this.change,-1).bind(this), false);
this.addRights[i].addEventListener("click", _.partial(this.change, 1).bind(this), false);
```